# VSTO visual studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, vsto

I am getting this error message:

[image: enter message screenshot]

For details:

> Name: 
>   From: file:///C:/Users/ACCOUNTING 02/Desktop/New Moon/12/Addin/bin/Debug/______Addin.vsto

**Exception Text:**

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.AddInAlreadyInstalledException: The customization cannot be installed because another version is currently installed and cannot be upgraded from this location. To install this version of the customization, first use Add or Remove Programs to uninstall this program: ______Addin. Then install the new customization from the following location: file:///C:/Users/ACCOUNTING 02/Desktop/New Moon/12/Addin/bin/Debug/______Addin.vsto
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.VerifySolutionCodebaseIsUnchanged(Uri uri, String subscriptionId, Boolean previouslyInstalled)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()

I run the program in visual studio and there is an error in .vsto

Can anyone provide a solution?

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message tells you to do?

Comment: Glad you seem to have solved it? Please do not "vandalize" your posts (delete the content). You may, if you wish, delete the post itself, but you don't have to. If there are no answers posted to it, the system itself will eventually remove it. But as long as it's still here, and contains complete information, it's possible others with a similar problem can profit from it. Removing the content, leaving "an empty shell", is really frowned upon, here :-)